# Empty cell validation while upload file in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, excel

Angular file upload how to implement empty cell validation. I am trying to upload Excel file in angular.

- Angular Excel file is uploading successfully. I have only 4 columns in my Excel and all columns are mandatory.
- I need to show one alert message if any cell is empty. All cells are mandatory in a row.

How can i do this using Angular. Please find the Example.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-excel-upload)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

type AOA = any[][];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sheet',
   templateUrl: './sheet.component.html',
})

export class SheetJSComponent {
  data: AOA = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
  wopts: XLSX.WritingOptions = { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' };
  fileName: string = 'SheetJS.xlsx';

  onFileChange(evt: any) {
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
      this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 }));
      console.log("data:",this.data);
      this.data.map(res=>{
        if(res[0] === "no"){
          console.log(res[0]);
        }else{
          console.log(res[0]);
        }
      })
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
  }


  export(): void {
    /* generate worksheet */
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(this.data);

    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false" />
    <table class="sjs-table">
        <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
            <td *ngFor="let val of row">
                {{val}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <button (click)="export()">Export!</button>
```

Can anyone please explain me how to achieve this?